# I am trying to display the different notes from my User object but it is only displaying blank spaces. Implementing jinja and flask-current_user metod

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8SL9.png)Here is my module for User and Note class. Here I have two classes for user and notes following a one to many structure.

```
class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50),unique=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    notes = db.relationship("Note") #mapping one user to many notes
    
class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("user.id")) #mapping a note to a particular user
```

Here is the html content. In this, when I try to implement {{ note.data }}, I just get blank spaces instead of the notes that is added. I am trying to figure out how to unpack the notes variable and display all the different notes listed inside user.notes

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block contains %}

<h1>Notes</h1>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="notes">
  {% for note in user.notes %}
  <li class="list-group-item">
    {{ note.data }}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="note" id="note" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your thoughts.."></textarea>
    </br>
    <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Note</button>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

The homepage function. I am updating the newly added note to the database and trying to call the home.html file by passing the currently logged in user. Hoping to display the newly added note to the webpage.

```
@pages.route('/',methods = ["GET","POST"])
@login_required
def home_page():
    if request.method=="POST":
        note = request.form.get("note")
        if len(note)<1:
            flash("Your note should contain atleast 1 character",category='error')
        else:
            new_note = Note(text=note,user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_note)
            db.session.commit()
            print(current_user.notes)
            flash("New note has been added!",category='success')
        
    return render_template("home.html",user=current_user)
```

Added the screenshot of the webpage for your reference.

Comment: do you mean `{{ note.text }}`?

Comment: Thank you. That worked.. Any idea why note.data wasn't working? Did they update the documentation?

Comment: which documentation are you referring?

Comment: I was referring a video where he had used {{ note.data }}. I guess maybe that's the old version of jinja. Can you share your reference for {{ note.text }}? I would be interested in reading it :)

Comment: I suggested after looking at `new_note = Note(text=note,user_id=current_user.id)`. I was not sure that would work, which is why I left a comment and not an answer